# Считывание строки по указателю byte*

Tags: python, ctypes

Есть функция из библиотеки dll, возвращаемое значение имеет тип byte*. Функция возвращает код ошибки и строку с результатом работы или детальным описанием ошибки. Как обратиться к этой строке из python.
Вот фрагмент кода:

```
lib = WinDLL('txmlconnector')
SetLogLevel = lib.SetLogLevel
SetLogLevel.restype = POINTER(c_byte)
SetLogLevel.argtype = (c_int)
res = SetLogLevel(5)
print(res)
```

Вывод будет примерно таким:

```
<__main__.LP_c_byte object at 0x01FF6EE0>
```

Как получить строку с результатом, а не её адрес?

Answer (score 2):

Решено использованием типа c_char_p вместо POINTER(c_byte).
Т.е. нужно так:

```
SetLogLevel.restype = c_char_p
```

Comment: `c_char_p` работает для байтовых строк, ограниченных нулём (`b'\0'`) (строки в Питоне не имеют подобного ограничения, например: `len(b'1\x002\x00') == 4` -- при путешествии через `c_char_p`, строка может обрезаться.  `c_char_p.from_param()` преобразует значение в Питоновскую строку. В общем случае, можно самому получить байты для произвольного массива байтов, возвращаемого как указатель `res` и длина `n`: [`bytearray(cast(res, POINTER(c_ubyte * n)).contents)`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7543675/4279)